# Get all the links from a URL then check whether URL exists or not

Tags: php

PHP Code :

```
$get_url="some url";
$content_of_url=file_get_contents($get_url);
$content_of_url = strip_tags($content_of_url,"<a>");
$get_string = preg_split("/<\/a>/",$content_of_url);
foreach ( $get_string as $val_get ){
    if( strpos($val_get, "<a href=") !== FALSE ){
        $val_get = preg_replace("/.*<a\s+href=\"/sm","",$val_get);
        $val_get = preg_replace("/\".*/","",$val_get);              
        $headers = @get_headers($val_get);              
        if($headers && strpos( $headers[0], '200')) { 
            $check_url = $val_get."    <b>URL Exist</b>"."<br/><br/>"; 
        } 
        else { 
            $check_url = $val_get."    <b>URL Doesn't Exist</b>"."<br/><br/>";  
        }               
        echo($check_url);
    }
}
```

It shows the incorrect result for some URLs that it doesn't exist or not working but actually that link is working.

Comment: Maybe the "incorrect" URLs don't respond with an HTTP 200, they may be a 301 or 302 instead.

Comment: Not working with 301 and 302 as well.